# Form_for work but doesn't save into table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a simple `form_for`but that doesn't work fully.

I have two table:
Users -> has_many -> Cvs

this is my form :

```
<%= form_for(:cvs, action: "create", html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
    Nom : <%= f.text_field :nom %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
def create
    @cv = Cv.new(cv_params)
    @cv.save
end
```

With cv_params :

```
def cv_params
    params.require(:cv).permit(:nom)
end
```

In my route.rb :

```
post 'createcv'       => 'static_pages#createcv'
```

My controller is `static_pages` and my view is `createcv`
The field appear when I load the view, I put something but nothing is create in the table (there is no error). How can I correct that please?

EDIT:

The logs

```
Started GET "/createcv" for ::1 at 2015-06-16 17:22:03 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#createcv as HTML
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Cv Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "cvs".* FROM "cvs" WHERE "cvs"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
Rendered static_pages/createcv.html.erb within layouts/application (10.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 582ms (Views: 570.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/createcv" for ::1 at 2015-06-16 17:22:12 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#createcv as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"28oSelskM87GZ/geLj6yl3tOrtvKktH/poBasO4pyt7I2QNKxw9HX4J+yS3cmisuzmGOGnr+6IxZdh+uQGDRDQ==", "cvs"=>{"nom"=>"hjsvqsv"}, "commit"=>"Save Cvs"}
 User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Cv Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "cvs".* FROM "cvs" WHERE "cvs"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
Rendered static_pages/createcv.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 643ms (Views: 629.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Well, in your routes you have `createcv`, and in your controller your have `create`. Try `=> 'static_pages#create'`, your view name is irrelevant in this situation.

Comment: I put the same that doesn't work. What is the "action" field exactly?

Comment: Please post the log.

Comment: Update your post with the output of `rake:routes` and your dev log when you are trying to submit your form.

Comment: logs added to the question

Comment: did you change your route `post 'createcv'       => 'static_pages#create'`

Comment: yes I change that (@Rajarshi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Rajarshi Das is fine, only it seems to me that you want to open your form by visiting /createcv. so change your routes to:

```
# routes.rb
get '/createcv', to: 'static_pages#new'
post 'create', to: 'static_pages#create'


# static_pages controller
def new
  @cv = Cv.new
end

def create
  @cv = Cv.new(cv_params)
  if @cv.save
    flash[:alert] = 'Cv created!'
  else
    render 'new'
    flash[:alert] = 'Error in form'
end

private
def cv_params
  params.require(:cv).permit(:nom) # :cv must be singular
end

# static_pages/new.html.erb view 
<%= form_for @cv do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :nom %>
    <%= f.text_field :nom %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
params.require(:cv).permit(:nom)
```

should be

```
params.require(:cvs).permit(:nom)
```

cause all params are nested inside `:cvs` not `:cv`

also, looking at your logs and route:

```
Processing by StaticPagesController#createcv
```

you need to rename your action to `createcv`.

Anyway, the routing in your app seems to be wrong... Unless you want it that way.

Ideally you should do something like this:

in `static_pages` controller, action `createcv` you'll initiate new CV object:

```
def createcv
  ...
  @cv = Cv.new
end
```

and in `createcv.html.erb` the form would be like this:

```
<%= form_for @cv do |f| %>
    Nom : <%= f.text_field :nom %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

rails will know that @cv in the form is a new object, and it will add the proper route to the form, that will point (depending on your app) to `/cvs` with `post method`.
That means when you submit the cv, action `create` from `cv_controller` should handle the rest of the process.
In this case you won't need the route you added, it should be there after you added 
`resources :cvs`

This is just an example that might not fit your needs, cause I wouldn't know how did you named your models, controllers, etc..